# Иконка кластера исчезает

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Использую clusterIconLayout: 'default#pieChart'. Данные загружаются через RemoteObjectManager.

Если в кластере менее 500-от меток или все метки имеют один цвет, то всё отображается нормально. 
Если более 500 и 1 метка имеет отличный от других цвет, то загружается пустая (прозрачная) svg.

Вот так это выглядит: http://c2n.me/3UQXilq

500 меток - не слишком то большой кластер, однако юзабилити резко падает из-за такого отображения.

Comment: похоже на баг на стороне API, посмотрим

Comment: А есть какие сроки исправления подобных багов? Вообще существуют какие-то перспективы на то, что это будет исправлено или пора писать костыль?

Comment: Версии API выходят примерно раз в месяц, поэтому лучше в любом случае поискать альтернативу. Проблема возникает только в пайчартах с таким неравным соотношением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение "в обход".

Ранее цвет иконки кластера определялся по полю features[]->options->iconColor (т.е. по цветам вложенных маркеров).

Теперь реализовали с помощью: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/layout.PieChart-docpage/#param-data.properties.data. Подсчитали инфу по цветам (при слишком большом перекосе - объединили цвета), передали её в поле properties->data в объект кластера.